# php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump

> @php artisan package:discover

In Client.php line 302:

Missing required option `access_token`.

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1